# Python Class Objects Attribute Referencing

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes. `a` and `b`.

In one of class `a`'s methods, I created an object of class `b`. One of class `b` attributes takes a function. So say I gave it a random function but does this function of class `b` have access to class `a`'s attribute? even though I didn't pass it in directly as a parameter?

```
class b:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute_function = None

class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp = 10
        self.counter = 0

    def temp(self):
        obj = b()
        obj.attribute_function = lambda self: self.counter < self.temp
        return obj.attribute_function()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #pass
    obj = a()
    print obj.temp()
```

In the above example, I tried to provide a really basic example, but if you run it, it doesn't work...

Revised Code, class `a` should look like this:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp = 10
        self.counter = 0

    def temp(self):
        obj = b()
        obj.attribute_function = lambda args: self.counter < self.temp
        return obj.attribute_function(1) # i added this 1 to fill in arg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
class b:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute_function = None

class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self._temp = 10
        self.counter = 0

    def temp(self):
        obj = b()
        obj.attribute_function = lambda self=self: self.counter < self._temp
        return obj.attribute_function()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = a()
    print obj.temp()
```

On problem you had is `self.temp = 10` which shadowed your method `temp()`.

Another problem: `lambda self: self.counter < self._temp`. Your lambda function was expecting an argument. But omitting `self` is not a good idea `lambda : self.counter < self._temp`, because if you call `obj.attribute_function()` somewhere where `self` is not available or has changed - it will not find `self` or use another `self`. `self=self` fixes that.

But generally such magic is an anti-pattern. Tell us what are your trying to achieve, and there should be a better way to do what you want. Otherwise this kind of code will ensure many headaches.

I think this is a better solution (called strategy pattern):

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def temp(self):
        return self.a.temp()

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._temp = 10
        self.counter = 0

    def temp(self):
        return self.counter < self._temp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = B(A())
    print obj.temp()
```

Comment: I apologize for the bad sample code. Im working on a rather complicated project and explaining it over SO is tough. But to correct my error, the `attribute_function`'s `self` parameter in my original code is another parameter for something entirely different. the `self` reference within the `attribute_function` is entirely from the creator class's attribute.

Comment: Please see my above revised code; with you help I get it. But just to confirm, referencing the attributes of that class `a` without implicitly passing in the parameter works correct? Is this safe?

Comment: > But just to confirm, referencing the attributes of that class a without implicitly passing in the parameter works correct? Is this safe?< It should work, and this is called `closure`. Think twice if you need it. The only think I would do: `obj.attribute_function = lambda args, self=self: self.counter < self.temp` to ensure that the correct `self` is used when your lambda is called. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not work because you have a name collision at `temp`

You have assigned `temp` to be both a method:

```
def temp(self):
```

and an attribute:

```
self.temp = 10
```